# Dealing with es6 modules .mjs in React SSR nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, es6-modules, server-side-rendering

I want to use nodejs to SSR my react component. Inside the react component, I use ES6 module `import {foo} from './bar'`

I don't want to transpile my code when running on server (other than running flow/typescript to strip off the typing)

But since nodejs doesn't support syntax like `import {foo} from './bar'`

How can I use React SSR to render my App.js with ES6 module without transpile (in which it call `import Button from './button'`)?

I also don't want to use babel-node (think it may not be production friendly?)

ps: so maybe nodejs version 10 is the answer?

Comment: you can precompile your react components with babel. you're asking a question that goes like "how can I drive a car without wheels?" either add the wheels, or use a car that already has wheels

Comment: even with node 10, it won't recognize JSX

Comment: Unless you write w/o JSX then there is no getting around not having transpiler.